# "Date", "Meeting", "Gathering" and "Appointment"

Tags: confusable

As far as I know, a romantic meeting can be called a "**date**". They both like each other. But when you meet a person who provide you with a service such as a dentist, doctor, psychologist, lawyer..., it is called an "**appointment**". And when you meet someone for business, it's called a "**meeting**". 
However, if I just meet my friends or a new girlfriend, I can say: "I'm meeting/seeing friends/a new girlfriend.
That's OK. "Learning English with Papa Teach Me" on Youtube said that. Both of them are full sentences, but I want a specific noun like "*the first date*" or "*the first gathering*" or "*the first meeting*". Which ones I can use? And if possible, could you explain your advice? 
Thanks in advance for any helping or advice.

Comment: You're looking for nouns that can be used for a relatively small group of people (let's say 8 or fewer) coming together for friendly conversation at a preordained place and time, perhaps over a meal or coffee?

Comment: Yes. I met a new girlfriend and 2 old ones at a small coffee shop and I'm really confused which nouns I should use in this situation.

Comment: At our recent **encounter** is very neutral, not indicating if it was even planned.

Comment: Keep in mind "appointment" is usually tied to a date/time.

Answer (score 1):

In American English you could say

At our last ...

> meeting
>
> get-together
>
> night-out

And you can refer to the meal itself as an occasion:

At our last...

> breakfast
>
> brunch
>
> lunch
>
> dinner
>
> coffee

or

If you don't mind a longer phrase instead of a single noun:

**The last time we met** or **The last time we got together** or **The last time we saw each other** or **The last time we had coffee** (lunch, dinner, etc).